# Code splitting with auto-registered dynamically imported Vue components

Tags: vue.js, webpack, laravel-mix

I am trying to use [this techniqe](https://medium.com/maatwebsite/reducing-vue-application-file-size-with-laravel-mix-e483f746d836). In short I am trying code splitting with auto-registered dynamically imported Vue components. My file structure is `js/utils/vue.js` and `js/components/***.vue`.

This is how my Vue components are loaded:

```
const files = require.context('../components', true, /\.vue$/i, 'lazy').keys();
files.forEach(file => {
    Vue.component(file.split('/').pop().split('.')[0], () => import(`${file}`));
});
```

But it results in an error:

> [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve async component: function () {
>       return **webpack_require**("./resources/js/utils lazy recursive ^.*$")("".concat(file));
>     }
>   Reason: Error: Cannot find module './MainNavbar.vue'

Manually registering the component, while still using dynamic import works.
`Vue.component('main-navbar', () => import('../components/MainNavbar.vue'));`

Why am I receiving this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit:

I found something [here](https://medium.com/maatwebsite/reducing-vue-application-file-size-with-laravel-mix-e483f746d836) that works for me:

```
const files = require.context('./', true, /\.vue$/i, 'lazy').keys();

files.forEach(file => {
    Vue.component(file.split('/').pop().split('.')[0], () => import(`${file}`));
});
```

---

Judging from the error message, your expression `() => import(`${file}`)` needs to prepend the context path, since you're not referencing that like in `() => import('../components/MainNavbar.vue')`

so maybe something like

```
const componentName = key.split('/').pop().split('.')[0]
Vue.component(file.split('/').pop().split('.')[0], () => import(`../components/${file}`));
```

works?